# Flutter FCM iOS Issue - APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using firebase_messaging v9.0.1 in my Flutter application. On configuring this library based on the https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example, I am able to receive the notification for android in both foreground and background states. But the same for iOS is not working. I am getting the below error,

> APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID ''. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

My iOS device is connected to internet and there were no network related issues while running this.

Do I want to call any other function apart from FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken() for iOS?
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue @Karthikeyan P?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, I went step by step again with firebase documentation and realize that the push notification capability was missing on debug and release modes.

Steps to solve the issue:

1. Go to xcode
2. Select runner
3. Signing & Capabilities
4. Check debug and release capabilities you need to have background modes and push notification

[image: push notification capability]

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration

Comment: I've set it all, but still get that error, any update solution?

Answer (score 2):

> Try running on a real device

Try this:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var firebaseToken : String = "";
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self;
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true;
    self.registerForFirebaseNotification(application: application);
    return true;
   // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
  }
   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken : Data){
    print("X__APNS: \(String(describing: deviceToken))")
       Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken;
    //Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod )
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("X_ERR",error);
    }
    
     func registerForFirebaseNotification(application : UIApplication){
    //    Messaging.messaging().delegate     = self;
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self ;
            let authOpt : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound];
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOpt, completionHandler: {_, _ in})
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self ;
        }else{
            let settings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)                
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications();
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate{
    func messaging(_messagin : Messaging, didRecieveRegistrationToken fcmToken : String){
        self.firebaseToken = fcmToken;
        print("X__FCM: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    }
    func messaging(_messagin : Messaging, didRecieve remoteMessage : Any){
        //self.firebaseToken = fcmToken;
        print("REMOTE__MSG: \(remoteMessage)")
    }
    func application(_ application : UIApplication,didRecieveRemoteNotification uinfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){
        print("WITH__APN: \(uinfo)")
    }
}
```

**podfile**

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

#  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.11.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+3
```

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767718/2082723) also

Answer (score 1):

The way I solve this issue, instead of running the application thru debug mode, I archive the app and download it thru ad hoc and somehow this solves the issue

Comment: Practiclly the same for me. Stop playing from XCode and ran from phone itself and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error too but in my case I had set up an APN certificate instead of an APN key in Firebase. I had to update my APN certificate in Firebase which had expired. This resolved the error and I could obtain a token with .getToken() in my app.